# How to get debit sum and credit sum on different column in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have data which has 2 column Transaction code('D' or 'C') and Transaction Amount. I want the sum of Debit Transaction in one column and Credit Transaction in another column. I want to perform this calculation using Mapping Data Flow.

Input Data:

```
Transactioncode  TransactionAmount
----------------------------------          
D                789  
C                450
C                 89
```

Output

```
DebitAmount CreditAmount
------------------------      
789         539
```

How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an Aggregate transformation. Keep the group by empty. For the aggregates, add 2: DebitAmount, CreditAmount. The formulas will be something like this:

DebitAmount: sumIf(Transactioncode == 'D', TransactionAmount)
CreditAmount: sumIf(Transactioncode == 'C', TransactionAmount)